# Close Spring WebSocket on JWT expiration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

I'm trying to implement some WebSocket endpoints and wanted to secure them and be available to only authenticated users. My application currently does plain JWT authentication with no OAuth.

I'm currently able to secure the WebSocket only for Authenticated users since I'm putting the initial HTTP request endpoint behind Spring Security thus it needs my Token in the cookies to be able to be authenticated, so for that step it seems to be OK from what I think.

The problem comes when the JWT expires, I wouldn't want my users to hold a WebSocket connection even though the JWT expired, my idea is to use an OutBoundChannelInterceptor to validate the JWT from the Spring WebSocket session attributes and then if it's ok send the message, if not throw an exception, but the interceptors doesn't grab the event when messages are sent, and even then they would only be closed when someone did an event. What is the best approach to this issue?

Here is my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Value("${jwtSecret}")
    private String secret;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .headers().contentTypeOptions().disable()
            .and()
        .cors()
            .and()
        .requestCache()
                .requestCache(new HttpSessionRequestCache())
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthenticatedRequestHandler());

        configureAuthorizeRequests(http);
        configureSessionManagement(http);
        configureCSRF(http);
        configureAddFilters(http, tokenHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfig.UnauthenticatedRequestHandler unauthenticatedRequestHandler() {
        return new SecurityConfig.UnauthenticatedRequestHandler();
    }

    public class UnauthenticatedRequestHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
            response.setStatus(401);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationService);
    }

    private void configureSessionManagement(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    }

    private void configureCSRF(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    private void configureAddFilters(HttpSecurity http, TokenHandler tokenHandler) {
        TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService(tokenHandler);
        http.addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/static/**",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**"
                );
    }

    private void configureAuthorizeRequests(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/version")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TokenHandler tokenHandler() {
        return new TokenHandler(secret);
    }
```

Here are my WebSocket Configuration:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/ws-message").setAllowedOrigins(
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ).addInterceptors(new WebSocketHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new AuthChannelInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new AuthChannelInterceptor());
    }
}
```

WebSocket Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
         messages
         .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.CONNECT, SimpMessageType.HEARTBEAT, SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE, SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT).permitAll()
         .anyMessage().permitAll()
         .simpDestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

WebSocketHandshakeInterceptor:

```
public class WebSocketHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                   ServerHttpResponse response,
                                   WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                   Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest();
        Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
        String token = getAuthTokenFromCookie(cookies);

        if (token == null) {
            return true;
        }

        attributes.put(TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, token);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest,
                               ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse,
                               WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler,
                               Exception e) {}
}
```

AuthChannelInterceptor:

```
public class AuthChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    private TokenHandler tokenHandler;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        if (accessor != null) {
            StompCommand command = accessor.getCommand();

            if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(command) || StompCommand.SEND.equals(command)) {
                Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getSessionAttributes(message.getHeaders());
                String authToken = (sessionAttributes != null) ? (String) sessionAttributes.get(TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME) : null;

                if (authToken == null) {
                   throw new BadCredentialsException("No auth token found in session attributes");
                } else {
                    tokenHandler.parseUserFromToken(authToken);
                }
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: `My application currently does plain JWT authentication with no OAuth` this makes no sense. And `getAuthTokenFromCookie(cookies);` this also makes no sense since tokens are sent as headers, and session cookies are sent as session cookies.

Comment: What I mean by that is that my application just receives a token from the Cookies and the way it validates it is by just checking the integrity of the JWT on Spring Security, no Authorization Server. For the second question, no, my JWT token is in my web browser cookies, I don't send them in any header, I saved the token at the start of the handshake in the WebSession attributes, similar as Spring Security does it with CSRF in their interceptors.

Comment: why would you do it that way as it is non standard and follows no security rfc whatsoever. Custom security is bad practice, and is one of the biggest reasons as to why there are thousands of breaches, because people insist on write strange custom security solutions that in the end dont end up secure i understand that you have problems when you are building this strange "solution". Good luck

Comment: I asked also what is the best solution for this issue, someone could have also thought about this and found out a better solution, there are a plethora of questions about JWT's and Spring Web Socket, yes indeed, maybe this is not the way but if you find it strange, point to the right direction, bashing all Spring Security tag questions that you find without actually giving any substance is not contribute.

Comment: did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: Nope @Rostam, what I did was to secure with Spring Security the initial handshake endpoints, I tried intercepting and validating each WS Request but it did not work well the ways that I did it.

Comment: I solved the problem by putting token in STOMP message header for every message and by verifying  it in ChannelInterceptor.

Comment: Oh yes that sounds alright. Thanks for sharing.